# Alternative period format on pgfgantt's ganttbar, possible?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, gantt

I would like to do Gantt chart in Latex thus I'm studying http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf, so far I can do:

[image]

by coding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[hgrid,vgrid,time slot format=isodate,time slot unit=month,x unit=10mm
]{2018-09-01}{2019-06-31} \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname} \\

    \ganttbar{Task 1               }{2018-09-01}{2018-10-31} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 2 - Do something}{2018-11-01}{2018-12-31} \\
    \ganttbar{Something else       }{2019-01-01}{2019-02-28} \\
    \ganttbar{Another task         }{2019-03-01}{2019-04-30}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have `\ganttbar{Task 1}{2018-09-01}{2}` as an alternative to `\ganttbar{Task 1}{2018-09-01}{2018-10-31}`. How to approch this solution?

Motivation for that: Well, with that, it will no be necessary to think if a month has 30, 31 or 28 days (while specifying end date).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a date as: `⟨year⟩-⟨month⟩-last`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[hgrid,vgrid,time slot format=isodate,time slot unit=month,x unit=10mm
]{2018-09-01}{2019-06-last} \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname} \\

    \ganttbar{Task 1               }{2018-09-01}{2018-10-last} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 2 - Do something}{2018-11-01}{2018-12-last} \\
    \ganttbar{Something else       }{2019-01-01}{2019-02-last} \\
    \ganttbar{Another task         }{2019-03-01}{2019-04-last}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```